# How to interrupt task in Scala?

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor

As I understand `Scala Actors` *cannot* be interrupted. Suppose now that I have a task with a timeout. If the task does not finish within the timeout I should stop it.

Suppose that the task is *interruptible* (e.g. performs blocking i/o upon an interruptible channel). In Java I can run the task in a separate thread and interrupt the thread on timeout.

Can I do that with `Scala Actors` ? Should I use Java threads instead ?

Comment: Scala Actors are deprecated as of 2.11. You should move to Akka now: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html

Comment: There is no reason you can't create a thread in exactly the same way in Scala. Seems like the best way to do what you want.

Comment: @Felix Thanks. I understand I can use threads rather than actors in this case. I wonder if this is considered good practice.

Comment: To be honest, I am not a complete fan of Akka because you will hand over a _LOT_ of control to the framework to the point where your actors are not so much actors as they are message-processors. Compared to Scala actors, which are unfortunately now deprecated, you do not define an act method in Akka, instead, you can only define a partialfunction to handle incoming messages.
To mimic the act method, you have to do weird stuff like change behaviour of the actor to work as a stack-machine using "become/unbecome". 
Trust me, unless you need specific features of Akka, go for threads.

Comment: To future proof your app, you could easily mock up some pattern-matching receive and still just use java threads + socket communication. Remember, message passing is _THE_ paradigm if you want to scale up to a network application later.

Comment: I met the same problem with Akka. Running `system stop ioActor` will send a message to `ioActor` rather than interrupting the Thread running `ioActor`. If `ioActor` is in a blocking operation, the message will not be processed and `ioActor` will continue blocking even though the operation is interruptible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420753/how-to-cancel-an-akka-actor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot interrupt an Actor if you follow the Actor model precisely. That is: if you do not want to share. This is proposed in the [How to cancel an Akka actor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420753/how-to-cancel-an-akka-actor) answer by using an AtomicBoolean for instance.

However the general answer is: you are trying to use Java threading idioms within actors. This is wrong. Rather than have a long running task, you should split your work into smaller batches.

From the [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html), Actor Best Practices:

> Actors should be like nice co-workers: do their job efficiently
>   without bothering everyone else needlessly and avoid hogging
>   resources. Translated to programming this means to process events and
>   generate responses (or more requests) in an event-driven manner.
>   Actors should not block (i.e. passively wait while occupying a Thread)
>   on some external entity—which might be a lock, a network socket,
>   etc.—unless it is unavoidable; in the latter case see below.

Can you do this with Scala Actors? No, you will run into the same issue because your problem is of conceptual nature, not related to the framework implementation.

Should you use Java Threads instead? If you want to follow the Java threading idioms, then yes: go for it. But if you want to use Actor concurrency you have to adopt a different thinking model to reap all the benefits.

Comment: ... but IO "efficiency" is often out of your control. It thus would be nice that an actor performing IO - a non pure Actor - can be interrupted when the IO can be.

Comment: In that case I assume you are talking about blocking IO? Because there is no reason to perform it if you are using Java 7. Akka offers already some nice IO building blocks.

Comment: Yes. Blocking IO. And some third party librairies are built around blocking IO, jdbc, http clients, etc...

Comment: How would you know you're interrupting the right Actor? You call Thread.interrupt() on some thread, but it may as well be processing the next actor before it sees the interrupt signal.

Comment: @ViktorKlang - Quite the opposite: nobody wants to call `Thread.interrupt()`. What would be nice is to have the possibility to call *somehting* on the actor performing IO that would `interrupt` the IO.

Comment: @ViktorKlang I found a [Cancellable trait](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.2/#akka.actor.Cancellable) in the docs. What is it used for? Is internal API? Is it related to this topic? I can't seem to find where said trait is used within the API...

Comment: @pagoda_5b: It's used for the scheduled tasks for the Scheduler, it doesn't abort/interrupt running tasks, it just marks them as not being interesting to execute.

Comment: @BGR: But the only way is to call Thread.interrupt() because that's the only thing that interrupts blocking IO. So my question is which Thread calls interrupt on which other Thread.

Comment: @ViktorKlang (contrarily to you) I do not know Akka internals enough. But we could imagine having an `interrupt()` method on the Actor/ActorRef or `System` instance (passing a reference of the actor). When the actor is running in a thread and if `interrupt` has been called, then ìnterrupt()` is called on that thread.

Comment: @BGR: But the actor is currently occupying a Thread, and it's currently blocked on an IO call. Which thread will call Thread.interrupted() and how do you make sure it doesn't interrupt the wrong thread (i.e. the actor woke up from the IO call and the next actor started processing on the now interrupted thread)

Comment: @BGR: We also need to consider performance and scalability when discussing any solution to this problem. If it was trivial, trust me, we would already have it. But it is only a half-solution, as if the actor is not blocked but just burning through a lot of CPU cycles, there is no clean way of taking the Thread back from it.

Comment: @ViktorKlang As I said, I do not know internals enough to discuss performance impacts, or triviality although I would be surprised that identifying the blocking thread is the tough issue. The point is that when you are facing blocking IO - and you cannot always avoid it- the actor is holding a thread and there is no way to "reclaim" it although the IO *is* interruptible. That is a potential performance penalty, not to mention the need of figuring a non-actor solution as suggested by Felix. Too bad.

Comment: @BGR: if you have an interrupt() method on the Actor it would need to process this message but it cannot since it is blocked on the IO call. So instead you would have to tell the thread processing the actor to interrupt. In Akka, a thread processes multiple actors in a batch (if its still the case, Viktor can tell you more). Now how do you know when calling your interrupt() method you interrupt the right actor? Maybe the thread made some progress. So you will need synchronization mechanisms and a lot of other questions arise. Should the actor be interrupted immediately next time its processed?

Comment: @JoaEbert When actor (say 'aio' -  a ref, url...) is performing blocking IO, it is using a thread. Calling something like `system.interrupt(iao)`, `system` should be able to identify the thread from the pool and send an interrupt.

Comment: Okay, so `system.interrupt` has to figure out which thread is actually processing the actor (race condition #1) and then it tries to interrupt that thread. This will lead exactly to the problem that the Thread might be processing the next actor already and you are interrupting the wrong actor (race condition #2). Of course you can add all the synchronization you need to perform this action but you really do not want to do that from a performance perspective since it will be a huge penalty for everyone.

Comment: To conclude: you are right that this _is_ possible in general. But the question is how to implement it efficiently without creating a lot of contention.

Comment: My point is that this is a general JVM problem with multiple inherent race-conditions. So if you can solve this problem in general, without creating a bottleneck, I'd be more than glad to add it.